# Unity3d Resources.Load() return null for static variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have next code:

```cs
public static AudioMixer audioMixer;

void Awake()
        {
            audioMixer = Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("Sounds/Mixer"); //Return null. Why?
        }
```

Also In asset next:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZpW1.png)

I don't understand, why I cannot set to a variable.
I try next variants, but it was unsucessful:

```cs
audioMixer = Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("Sounds/Mixer");
audioMixer = Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("Sounds/Mixer.mixer");
audioMixer = Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("Assets/Sounds/Mixer");
audioMixer = Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("Assets/Sounds/Mixer.mixer");
audioMixer = Resources.Load("Assets/Sounds/Mixer.mixer") as AudioMixer;
```

Help me please,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file must be in Assets/Resources in order to access that.
[Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) Have a look at this for more info.

> The path is relative to any folder named Resources inside the Assets folder of your project.

Create a new folder "Resource" and move the sounds folder to that.

There is no need to mention Assets or Resources folder in the path.

```
Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("Sounds/Mixer");
```